# IdThreadComponent (Indy 9) in Delphi 2007 Error

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm using IdTCPClient and IdThreadComponent to get some information for a barcode reader. This code, with some changes is working in Delphi 11 and Indy 10 but not in Delphi 2007 and Indy 9:

```
procedure TPkgSendF1.IdThreadComponent1Run(Sender: TIdCustomThreadComponent);
var
  s: String;
begin
  s := IdTCPClient1.ReadLn('&', 20000, 1500);
  TThread.Queue(nil, procedure  // <== Expected @ but received PROCEDURE
                begin
                  ProcessRead(s);
                end);
end;

// [DCC Error] PkgSendF1.pas(239): E2029 Expression expected but 'PROCEDURE' found

procedure TPkgSendF1.ProcessRead(AValue: string);
begin
  Memo1.Text := AValue;
end;
```

If I don't use the TThread.Queue I miss some readings.
I'll appreciate any help.
Francisco Alvarado

Comment: In your code you use an anonymous method as the second parameter for ``TThread.Queue``, but those have not been introduced in ``Delphi 2007`` yet! And your code does not compile: You call a method ``ProcessRead``, but declared one with the name ``ProcessTray``!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot to rename the declaration in my question. But  how I can use the method in Delphi 2007?

Comment: @FAlvarado see the answer I just posted. On a side note, why not upgrade D2007 to Indy 10?

Comment: Thank you Remy. I wish I could upgrade this and other apps that communicates to an old TCP Server. Several months ago you help me with a similar issue when upgrading to Indy 10 and Delphi 11 but when the sent message is more than 100 characters the server gets the message incomplete. This is an application using that server and that's why I can't upgrade. I have to uses an old laptop with Delphi 2007 installed only for this applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous methods did not exist yet in Delphi 2007, they were introduced in Delphi 2010.  As such, `TThread.Queue()` in D2007 only had 1 version that accepted a `TThreadMethod`:

```
type
  TThreadMethod = procedure of object;
```

Which means you need to wrap the call to `ProcessRead()` inside a helper object that has a `procedure` with no parameters, eg:

```
type
  TQueueHelper = class
  public
    Caller: TPkgSendF1;
    Value: String;
    procedure DoProcessing;
  end;

procedure TQueueHelper.DoProcessing;
begin
  try
    Caller.ProcessRead(Value);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TPkgSendF1.IdThreadComponent1Run(Sender: TIdCustomThreadComponent);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := IdTCPClient1.ReadLn('&', 20000, 1500);
  with TQueueHelper.Create do
  begin
    Caller := Self;
    Value := s;
    TThread.Queue(nil, DoProcessing);
  end;
end;
```

FYI, Indy (both 9 and 10) has an asynchronous `TIdNotify` class in the `IdSync` unit, which you can use instead of using `TThread.Queue()` directly, eg:

```
uses
  IdSync;

type
  TMyNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  public
    Caller: TPkgSendF1;
    Value: String;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  end;

procedure TMyNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  Caller.ProcessRead(Value);
end;

procedure TPkgSendF1.IdThreadComponent1Run(Sender: TIdCustomThreadComponent);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := IdTCPClient1.ReadLn('&', 20000, 1500);
  with TMyNotify.Create do
  begin
    Caller := Self;
    Value := s;
    Notify;
  end;
end;
```